# Recuperar variável dentro da função JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, websql

Estou fazendo um login em JS + WebSQL, mas estou com dificuldades em pegar o valor da variável.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
function login() {
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM usuarios', [], function (tx, resultado) {
      let rows = resultado.rows;
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var usuario = rows[i].usuario;
        var senha = rows[i].senha;
      }
      alert("Aqui funciona: " + usuario);
    });
  });

  if (($("#usuario").val() == usuario) || ($("#senha").val() == senha)){
    window.location='painel.html';
  }else{
    alert("Aqui não funciona: " + usuario);
  }
}
```

Comment: Vc está declarando as variáveis `usuario` e `senha` dentro de uma `function`, e com isso essas variáveis terão escopo restrito dentro dessa `function`. Coloque o `if...else` dentro da  mesma `function`, logo após o `for`. Até porque acredito que o `if` é executado antes da consulta ao WebSQL, e com isso as variáveis sequer existem ainda, e mesmo que existissem, não teriam os valores da consulta ao banco.

Comment: @Sam, qual a forma correta de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A declaração e o uso das variáveis `usuario` e `senha` estão ocorrendo em escopos diferentes.

Para que compreenda o que está acontecendo preparei um exemplo simplificado replicando o mesmo erro:

```js
function teste() {

  (function() {
    var variavelLocal = 33; // a variavelLocal tem sua visibilidade restrita a 
                            // função anônima.
  })();


  console.log(variavelLocal); // Aqui vai dar ERRO o método console.log()
                              // não consegue enxergar a definição da variavelLocal

}


teste();
```

Nesse primeiro exemplo a `variavelLocal`  é visível apenas dentro do escopo em que foi declarada.

Para corrigir é suficiente declarar `variavelLocal` em um contexto mais abrangente:

```js
function teste() {

  var variavelLocal; // A variavelLocal é declara dentro do contexto da função teste.

  (function() {
    variavelLocal = 33; // Nesse casoa palavra chave var deve ser retirada pois não 
                        //queremos outra variável local a função anônima
  })();


  console.log(variavelLocal); // Funciona

}


teste();
```

Para corrigir o seu código é aplicar o mesmo princípio:

```
function login() {
  // usuario e senha declarados no escopo mais elevado dentro login()
  var usuario;
  var senha;
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM usuarios', [], function (tx, resultado) {
      let rows = resultado.rows;
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // Importante aqui retirar a palavra-chave var para que possamos atribuir 
        // valor ao invéz de redeclarar usuario e senha como variáveis locais
        // dentro de um escopo mais interno.
        usuario = rows[i].usuario;
        senha = rows[i].senha;
      }
      alert("Aqui funciona: " + usuario);
    });
  });

  // Agora usuario e senha são visíveis
  if (($("#usuario").val() == usuario) || ($("#senha").val() == senha)){
    window.location='painel.html';
  }else{
    alert("Agora funciona: " + usuario);
  }
}
```